# Using bootstrap navbar in bootjack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, bootjack

I'm using twitter bootstrap's CSS to create a [standard bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and then calling `Dropdown.use();` which makes the navbar work automagically.

[image: bootstrap navbar with bootjack dropdown]

When I re-size the page or view it on mobile, the navbar displays this menu button which does nothing when you click on it.

[image: bootstrap navbar in mobile mode]

How would I go about wiring this menu button with dquery / bootjack to display a menu as show in this example:

[image: bootstrap responsive navbar example]

(PS, loving bootjack, thanks to everyone who worked on it!!!)

**To clarify**, I do not want to include jquery and bootstrap js to make it work, my whole dart app including 400+ files (images, html, dart, less, etc) is under 400kB and adding those js libraries will make the app explode in size. I'm merely looking for the mechanism that bootstrap is using to make that menu button work so that I can rewrite it in dart / dquery / bootjack or if there's already a bootjack mechanism that can do it, how to use it.

**Update, some code as requested:**

pubspec.yaml:

```
....
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  bootjack_datepicker: any
  less_dart: any
  bootjack: any
  browser: any
  http: any
transformers:
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-experimental-mirrors]
- less_dart:
    entry_point: web/styles/main.less
    build_mode: dart
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    ....
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Application</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Item<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#itemss-list">Items</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#foo-bar">Foo Bar</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#item-create">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                Create Item
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        ...

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.less:

```
@import 'web/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
@import 'web/styles/bootjack-calendar/calendar.less';

@media screen {

  body {
    background: #FEFEFE;
  }

  ...

}
```

main.dart:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'pages/pages.dart';
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;
import 'package:dquery/dquery.dart';
import 'package:bootjack/bootjack.dart';
import 'package:bootjack_datepicker/bootjack_datepicker.dart';

...

void main() {

    ...

    // enable bootjack functionality
    Transition.use();
    Calendar.use();
    Dropdown.use();
    Modal.use();

    ...

}
```

Comment: can you show your  code...

Comment: added all relevant code as requested.

Comment: I think your missing bootstrap js and css link...its working fine in jsfiddle..

Comment: sorry dude..i misunderstand the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the classes on a working navbar while toggling it a couple of times, I've realised it's pretty simple - adding in / out to the classes makes the navbar pop in / out when in mobile view.

```
ButtonElement navbarToggle = querySelector("button.navbar-toggle");
navbarToggle.onClick.listen((e){
    DivElement menu = querySelector("div.navbar-collapse");
    if (menu.classes.contains("in")){
        menu.classes
            ..remove("in")
            ..add("out");
    } else if (menu.classes.contains("out")){
        menu.classes
            ..remove("out")
            ..add("in");
    }
});
```